# VueJS pass custom property to child component via property value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component named `controls`:

```
<li class="controls__item" v-if="options[0].save == 'show'"> 
   <button class="btn" :options[0].saveAttr>Save</button>
</li>
```

I'm having trouble rendering an attribute defined in the `options` property:

```
<controls :options='[{ save: "show", saveAttr: "sampleAttr='0' "}]'></controls>
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<button class="btn" sampleAttr='0'>Save</button>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct syntax for binding in Vue.

If the name of the attribute to bind to is never going to change, you should specify the name in the `controls` component:

```
<li class="controls__item" v-if="options[0].save == 'show'"> 
  <button class="btn" :sampleAttr="options[0].saveAttr">Save</button>
</li>
```

And just change the options to pass in a value for `saveAttr`:

```
<controls :options='[{ save: "show", saveAttr: "0" }]'></controls>
```

---

If the name of the attribute (or the number of attributes) could change, then you should pass an object to the `v-bind` directive like so:

```
<li class="controls__item" v-if="options[0].save == 'show'"> 
  <button class="btn" v-bind="options[0].saveAttrs">Save</button>
</li>
```

And then pass in an object for `saveAttrs`:

```
<controls :options='[{save : "show", saveAttrs: { sampleAttr: 0 }]'></controls>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with your testdata (just a little clean up) let's say you have two buttons since it seems like you want to do that later on. I'm not yet sure what the save : "show" is supposed to do - so I do my best to give a flexible example.

```
[{
   'text': 'Save',
   'click': function() {  alert('save'); }
,{
   'text': 'Delete',
   'click': function() {  alert('delete'); }
}]
```

Not lets say you have that testdata in your component called "controls"

```
<controls :options="[{'text': 'Save','click': function() {  alert('save'); },{'text': 'Delete','click': function() {  alert('delete'); }}]"> </controls>
```

As we can see your controls has an property called options. So your code for your component should look like:

```
<template>
    <div class="controls">

        <li class="controls__item" v-for="control in options"> 
          <button class="btn" @click="control.click">{{ control.text }}</button>
        </li>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['options']
    }
</script>
```

You need to define the prop you want to bind on the component (options). Options is now bound according to our test date. Since it's an array we can use v-for to loop through it. We then bind the given text as button content and the given click function as on click event.

I hope this helps.